# Проверка изменения файлов на сервере

Tags: javascript, php, html

Подскажите, возможно ли как то отслеживать изменения файлов в определенной папке на сервере с помощью js или php. то есть, кто то загружает фото в папку, а скрипт видит эту загрузку и имя файла загружаемого и копирует его в строку в html файле

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то загружает файл или же меняет его имя, это должно происходит и в базе данных (если конечно это реализовано). Через бд можно отслеживать всё это.

Предположим у тебя есть таблица в бд files, куда попадают все файлы загруженные на сайт, делаешь у себя в админке выборку всех файлов с этой таблицы и ты отслеживаешь все изменения